# Why window.setTimeout throws an exception in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, settimeout

Here's my code:

```
save: function(){
    window.setTimeout(recipeControlsViewModel.saveWOTimeOut(),500);
},
```

Here's the error I get only in IE9 when the "Display a notification about every script error" option is checked in Internet Options in IE9. This doesn't happen in FireFox, Chrome or IE10 & IE11.

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument
```

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: You're invoking the function and passing its return value instead of passing the function itself to `setTimeout`.

Comment: How can I pass the function itself into setTimeout?

Comment: The most direct answer is  to remove the `()` from the end. That's what invokes it. But that may cause another problem. The method being invoked may (and probably does) rely on the object it's being called from. In that case, you'd pass an anonymous function that invokes the method from the object. @Pointy shows how below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to wrap that function call in an anonymous function:

```
save: function(){
    window.setTimeout(function() { recipeControlsViewModel.saveWOTimeOut() },500);
},
```

Alternatively, from IE9 forward you can use `.bind()`:

```
save: function(){
    window.setTimeout(recipeControlsViewModel.saveWOTimeOut.bind(recipeControlsViewModel) },500);
},
```

though in this case that's more typing. The `.bind()` function returns another function that's "bound" to the object you pass it. What that means is that the returned function will call the original function (the one referred to by your "saveWOTimeOut" property) with the argument ("recipeControlsViewModel") as the value of `this`.

Comment: or simpler OP can just drop the ()

Comment: I just tried the first solution and it worked. Which one of these solutions will be more stable and will work most often in most browsers?

Comment: @epascarello yes, assuming that function doesn't expect `this` to be anything.

Comment: @goe the first one is simple and will work everywhere.

Comment: Nice explanation of bind.